# Creating Active Directory service in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm using Microsoft Azure through my Microsoft Dreamspark account. I need to use Active Directory for a project so I logged into `portal.azure.com` and went to the Marketplace. The `Create` button for Active Directory is greyed out and there is the following message underneath it:

NOT YET IN PREVIEW: Go to the [Azure portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) and start using this service right now.

The link is `manage.windowsazure.com/` but when I click it, it redirects me to a bunch of URLs and finally comes back to `portal.azure.com` which is where I was at before.

Any help would be great!

EDIT Here's what the panel looks like. Notice the greyed out Create button.

[image]

Comment: I just tried at https://manage.windowsazure.com and it works as it should. Can you try to log out and log in at https://manage.windowsazure.com directly to avoid the redirect you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Edit2: I have a one year old mail conversation with billing support where I claimed I had a pending marked on the following image for 24 hours. Can you check yours and say what it says? The problem resolved it self around 24 hours and support claims they didnt do nothing which could be an indication of very long provisioning time.
[image]

Edit: I think you should wait an hour or two if you just created you BizSpark account. I had the same issue when I created mine. Think it has to do with your account not being provisioned over all required servers.

This is the way it should look at the old portal, it works as it is supposed to, just tried it.

If you are being redirected I suggest you remove your cookies and try to login directly to https://manage.windowsazure.com/

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. I cleared cache on Chrome and went straight to https://manage.windowsazure.com/ but it still redirected me back to Portal. I also tried it on Firefox where it was the first time I logged into Azure cloud and it still did the same thing.

Comment: @Carpetfizz Did you just create your BizSpark user account? See updated answer in that case, otherwise I'll just delete my answer.

Comment: ohh that could be the case. Yes, I just created my Dreamspark account maybe less than 2 hours ago. I think you're right about the server provisioning. I'll report back after checking a couple hours from now.

Comment: No luck.. It's been 4 hours and my account still does the same thing. Even tried clearing the cache

Comment: @Carpetfizz I checked my conversation with billing support and updated my answer accordingly. I haveone BizSpark account left and will set it up tonight and document the process. That would give you a reference for every step taken.

Comment: @Carpetfizz So I started my blog post about this and.. added the wrong email address in My BizSpark. Deleted it to create a new one just to find out it couldnt be done. I had 4 additional BizSpark accounts and deleted ones are included! I'm trying to solve this with MSDN support and the promised blog post wont be deliverred as I said earlier. By the way, have you logged into your https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions and set your primary user as Service Administrator for the BizSpark subscription? This might be of help.. http://thesociablegeek.com/azure/adding-users-to-bizsparkazure/

Comment: hey thank you so much for the detailed blog entry. I think the difference might be that I'm using Dreamspark and not Bizspark. I think Dreamspark accounts are restricted to the new portal.

Comment: @Carpetfizz No, that is not the case :) You should have access to both portals since the use of services are divided among them dependent of where the implementing Azure team choose to implement it. Did you take a look at https://account.windowsazure.com/subscriptions?

Comment: thanks for the link, I went to the URL you provided and this is what it gave me http://i.imgur.com/f3uua9w.png

Comment: @Carpetfizz Click it, then click "Edit subscription details", the change service administrator to an outlook account of yours and log in to manage.wnidowsazure.com with it and I think it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi at present Active Directory isn't available in Azure for DreamSpark

Current Services are

Microsoft Azure for DreamSpark gets you started with the services you need to develop in the cloud at no cost:

•Azure App Service Web Apps is a part of a fully managed cloud offering that enables you to build and deploy web apps in seconds. Use ASP.NET, Java, PHP, Node.js or Python. Run popular web apps and CMS solutions. Set up continuous integration and deployment workflows with VSO, GitHub, TeamCity, Hudson or BitBucket – enabling you to automatically build, test and deploy your web app on each successful code check-in or integration tests.

•MySQL Database from ClearDB adds the power of MySQL to your Web Apps. With clearDB MySQL you can deploy more kinds of web apps and CMS solutions such as Wordpress, Joomla, Acquia Drupal, phpBB, and more.

•Application Insights provides a 360° view across availability, performance and usage of your ASP.NET services and mobile applications for Windows Phone, iOS and Android platforms. Search and analyze your data to continuously improve your application, prioritize future investments and improve overall customer experience.

•Visual Studio Online is the fastest and easiest way yet to plan, build, and ship software across a variety of platforms. Get up and running in minutes on our cloud infrastructure without having to install or configure a single server.

These will be updated and new feature added keep checking https://[www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=99](http://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=99)